# Como mover una imagen de una carpeta a otra en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net, imagen

quisiera si es posible mover una imagen de una carpeta a otra con VB.net, tengo la carpeta y el nombre definido del archivo, así como su extensión y la quisiera mover a otra carpeta. debido a que la tengo que mapear en esa ruta.

Esta de la siguiente manera:

```
-carpetaImagenes
|--carpetaProductos
|  |--**Posición donde se tiene que mover la imagen**
|--imagenParaMover.jpg **Imagen que tiene que ser movida**
```

Comment: Para poderte ayudar es importante que pongas dentro de tú pregunta la porción de código con la que estas intentando realizar esto.

Comment: Has buscado algo,como por ejemplo `File.Move`?